# reducing a value in an array not working

Tags: php, arrays, prestashop

I have the following code on prestashop. I am trying to reduce the {$combination.price} by 20%. But changing the array at the end does not seem to work? i.e. {$combination.price/1.2)

Can anyone help me, how i can return the price with a reduction of 20%?

```
{if isset($groups)}
// Combinations
{foreach from=$combinations key=idCombination item=combination}
    var specific_price_combination = new Array();
    var available_date = new Array();
    specific_price_combination['reduction_percent'] = {if $combination.specific_price AND $combination.specific_price.reduction AND $combination.specific_price.reduction_type == 

'percentage'}{$combination.specific_price.reduction*100}{else}0{/if};
    specific_price_combination['reduction_price'] = {if $combination.specific_price AND $combination.specific_price.reduction AND $combination.specific_price.reduction_type == 

'amount'}{$combination.specific_price.reduction}{else}0{/if};
    specific_price_combination['price'] = {if $combination.specific_price AND $combination.specific_price.price}{$combination.specific_price.price}{else}0{/if};
    specific_price_combination['reduction_type'] = '{if $combination.specific_price}{$combination.specific_price.reduction_type}{/if}';
    specific_price_combination['id_product_attribute'] = {if $combination.specific_price}{$combination.specific_price.id_product_attribute|intval}{else}0{/if};
    available_date['date'] = '{$combination.available_date}';
    available_date['date_formatted'] = '{dateFormat date=$combination.available_date full=false}';
    addCombination({$idCombination|intval}, new Array({$combination.list}), {$combination.quantity}, {$combination.price}, {$combination.ecotax}, {$combination.id_image}, 

 '{$combination.reference|addslashes}', {$combination.unit_impact}, {$combination.minimal_quantity}, available_date, specific_price_combination);
    {/foreach}

{/if}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$price * 0.8` or `$price - ( $price * 0.2 )` either way they have the same end result.  The first one is the variable $price multiplied by 80% which would be the price at an 20% deficit.  The second example is the variable $price minus the variable $price multiplied by 20% which would be the price minus 20% of the price assuming you replace $price with the actual variable you are trying to return with a 20% deficit.